# How to I set document ID or ID to PDF file via terminal?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pdf, file-metadata, exif

Hello I am writing a bash script, this script must give ID to pdf file. How do I solve the this, is there a way?
Example as using bash shell.

Document ID is:

```
$ exiftool example.pdf | grep 'Document ID'
Document ID        : uuid:d037451d-240e-4d82-ba6d-92390b1d2962
```

For example:

```
$ pdftool --setDocID "newID" example.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exiftool -DocumentID="uuid:$newID" example.pdf
```

see examples on `man exiftool`

Comment: thanks, it's works

Comment: `newID=$(uuidgen) && exiftool -DocumentID="uuid:$newID" example.pdf` So is such a use suitable?